# User Model Error:type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter

I need help with this UserModel and this UserEntity when I tried to read json from firebase. I have problems with retrieve a map from firebase. I have this error:type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast.
I am not sure how to do this correctly
Can you help me?

Here is my code:

User Model:

```
class UserModel extends UserEntity {
  const UserModel(
      {super.name,
      super.uid,
      super.ins,
   });

  factory UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    var snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    return UserModel(
        uid: snapshot['uid'],
        name: snapshot['name'],
        ins: (snapshot['ins'] as List)
            .map((e) => InsModel.fromSnapshot(e))
            .toList(),
      );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'uid': uid,
        'name': name,
        'ins': ins
      };
}

class InsModel extends InsEntity {
  const InsModel({super.category, super.type, super.owned});

  factory InsModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    var snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    return InsModel(
        category: snapshot['category'],
        type: snapshot['type'],
        owned: snapshot['owned']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {'category': category, 'type': type, 'owned': owned};
}
```

User Entity:

```
class UserEntity extends Equatable {
  final String? uid;
  final String? name;
  final List<InsEntity>? ins;

  const UserEntity(
      {
      this.uid,
      this.name,
      this.ins
     });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        uid,
        name,
        ins,
      ];
}

class InsEntity extends Equatable {
  final String? category;
  final String? type;
  final bool? owned;

  const InsEntity({this.category, this.type, this.owned});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [category, type, owned];
}
```

Comment: It simply seems the snapshot gives a list and not a map. Maybe try to print `snap.data()` to verify

Comment: No, it gives a map. Here is the print.{ins: {owned: true, category: Clar, type: Sib} uid: 4YQ2EZiAk9NAtdIacS7BrgHgVeG3 , name: Diego}

Comment: Actually `ins` is a map and not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `ins` is a map and not a list. So a user has only one of them. Then you need to change in the entity

```
final List<InsEntity>? ins;
```

to

```
final InsEntity? ins;
```

and in the model

```
return UserModel(
    uid: snapshot['uid'],
    name: snapshot['name'],
    ins: (snapshot['ins'] as List)
        .map((e) => InsModel.fromSnapshot(e))
        .toList(),
  );
```

to

```
return UserModel(
    uid: snapshot['uid'],
    name: snapshot['name'],
    ins: InsModel.fromSnapshot(snapshot['ins']),
  );
```

and change the `fromSnapshot` of `InsModel` to

```
  factory InsModel.fromSnapshot(Map<String, dynamic> snapshot ) {
    return InsModel(
        category: snapshot['category'],
        type: snapshot['type'],
        owned: snapshot['owned']);
  }
```

(and maybe rename it to `fromMap`)

Comment: that was an error, an user can have many ins, I've just changed my database to array of map. Now if I print snap is {name:Diego, ins: [{owned: true, category: Clar, type: Sib}],  uid: 4YQ2EZiAk9NAtdIacS7BrgHgVeG3}

Comment: But I still have an error: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'

Comment: @Mus like I wrote in this answer you need to change the `InsModel.fromSnapshot` to take a Map instead of DocumentSnapshot